# FullCalendar redefine a long event as an all day event

Tags: fullcalendar

I am using FullCalendar and iCalendar2FullCalendar to feed in the .ICS files from our various iCloud accounts. This works great at rendering all the events from our shared calendars.

I’m making a small display and am using the ‘agendaDay’ view. I like that all day events sit at the top and can see any scheduling conflicts below.

However, I have some events that run over a number of days, for example from 1700hrs Friday to 1900hrs Sunday my daughter will be with me. On the agendaDay view this will show as a solid bar throughout all of saturday across each hour, and I’m wondering if there is a way to render events over a certain duration as an all day event instead?

I’ve played with the eventRender callback but whilst I’m able to change the event properties the event still renders as if the changes were never made.

Here’s my code, in this revision i’ve applied a fixed date in the hope it would draw as an all day event but no luck!:

```
        $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
          header: {
                left: 'prev,next today',
                center: '',
                right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
            },
          defaultView: 'month',
          editable: false,
          aspectRatio: 0.77,


            eventRender: function(event, element, view) { 

                var dur = event.end - event.start; //event duration
                var days = dur / 86400000;

                if(days > 1 || event.end == null){ // needs altering to show as all day event.

                    console.log('long event - all day?' + event.allDay);
                    event.allDay = true;
                    console.log(event.title + ' - all day?' + event.allDay);            

                            console.log(event.title + ' - starts:' + EpochToDate(event.start));         
                            console.log(event.title + ' - ends:' + EpochToDate(event.end)); 

                     event.start = '2018-07-23T10:00:00';   
                     event.end = '2018-07-24T10:00:00';
                     console.log (event);
                 }
             }    
            });
        })
```

Comment: trouble is that 1700 on one day to 1900 on another day means that the first and last days are not "all day". An "all-day" event in fullCalendar's terms must be either one single day, or several days where the event covers the whole day on _all_ of the days. So...if you're happy to lose the detail of the 1700 and 1900 you could simply mark the event using `allDay: true` and get a simplified display. If you need those times to be displayed, then you have no choice really except to accept that it will be displayed as simply a long-running timed event.

Comment: P.S, The changes you made in eventRender fail because the purpose of eventRender is that you _read_ from `event`'s properties and _write_ to `element`, which is the HTML element that has already been constructed based on the `event` data, and which soon will be rendered onto the calendar. The idea is to allow you to update the HTML, not the event. fullCalendar has already used the event and will ignore it after this point. It's just your chance to use the event and customise the HTML. https://fullcalendar.io/docs/eventRender explains: "The `eventRender` callback function can modify `element`"

Comment: If you want to customise the event data itself, use `eventDataTransform`, which runs before the event is rendered. Any changes you make to the event data here will be seen by fullCalendar when it's creating the HTML for that event. See https://fullcalendar.io/docs/eventDataTransform

Comment: Thanks AD, will give `eventDataTransform` a go tonight. I was able to change certain properties of `element`, such as `innerText` which was then rendered.

Comment: Will `eventDataTransform` still trigger when the event source is .ICS file, loaded like this `$('#calendar').fullCalendar('addEventSource', fc_events(this.response, ics.event_properties))`?

Comment: fullCalendar doesn't directly support ICS format. I assume your `fc_events` method turns it into JS objects? But to answer your question, the source of the data is irrelevant. AFAIK the eventDataTransform callback will execute for every event added to the calendar, no matter where it comes from or how it's added.

Comment: I’m not too sure actually - I’m using `https://github.com/leonaard/icalendar2fullcalendar/tree/gh-pages/demo` Am i overthinking at and there another config option available? Essentially  any rendered event over x hours, is changed to an all day event?

Comment: Well that function must be written into your JS files somewhere, even if you didn't write it yourself you can easily use the browser's debug tools to find it. But it seems obvious that's what it must be doing. Anyway, like I said it doesn't really matter for the purpose of your question. You could write code to do the change you've suggested in eventDataTransform certainly, if you wanted to. It's up to you, per your requirements. Whatever you do, eventDataTransform is a sensible place to do it.

Comment: Thanks - Is there any usage examples, the ones I tried either broke things completely or resulted in no rendered events! I asssume the process of determining the duration (within the eventDataTransform function) and then applying the change the event.allDay is all I need to get done?

Comment: yep that's all you need to get done. Remember to write a `return` statement at the end which returns the new version of the event, otherwise you will indeed end up with no rendered events. The documentation does mention this.

Comment: Added an answer, thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here’s what I used in the end, thanks to @ADyson.

```
 $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
          header: {
                left: 'prev,next today',
                center: '',
                right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
            },
          defaultView: 'month',
          editable: false,
          aspectRatio: 0.77,
        eventDataTransform: function (eventData) {

                var dur = eventData.end - eventData.start; //total event duration

                if(dur >= 18000000 || eventData.end == null){ // 5 hours

                        eventData.allDay = true;


                        //eventData.end needs ammending to 00:00:00 of the next morning
                        if (dur > 86400000) {


                        var m = moment(eventData.end);
                        var roundDown = m.startOf('day');
                        var day2 = moment(roundDown).add(1, 'days')

                        eventData.end = day2.toString();

                        }

                }

            return(eventData);  
        },

    });
```